# Query the DB DATETIME column just by date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

I have a column in the DB with `DATETIME` type and is with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Nevertheless, as information I am given just the date (and I don't care about the time). So how should I query the DB to search that column just by date, even though the value contains both the date and the time?

*Update:*

Here's the PHP code where I am trying to select the entities:

```
public static function getTripsWithDrivers($route_from = null, $route_to = null, $date = null)
{
   $trips = Trip::whereRouteFrom($route_from)->whereRouteTo($route_to)->whereStartDate($date);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Best solution would be `BETWEEN date1 AND date2`, where `date1` would be with time `00:00:00`, and `date2` with time `23:59:59`. This will use the index on the field, if you have one. Function `DATE(date)` will not be using index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySql [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```php
$trips = Trip::where(DB::raw('DATE(route_from)'), '=', $route_from)
             ->where(DB::raw('DATE(route_to)'), '=', $route_to)
             ->where(DB::raw('DATE(start_date)'), '=', $date)
```

Comment: Hint: this will not use any index used on date field.

Answer (score 1):

User where filter as the following:

```
WHERE "datetime column" like '2015-04-06%'
```